# A particular sub-domain in a virtual host is not redirecting, but others succed

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, https, http, redirect

I like my website to be accessible by `example.org` or `https://example.org` not `www.example.org`.

So I want `http://www.example.org` to redirect to `http://example.org` and `http://www.example.org` to `https://example.org`.

But an interesting thing happens:

`https://www.example.org` redirects to `https://example.org` **but not `http://www.example.org` to `http://example.org`**

My main.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /pathtocert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /pathtokey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My www.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    RedirectPermanent / http://example.org

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.org

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    RedirectPermanent / https://example.org

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /pathtocert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /pathtokey.pem
</VirtualHost>



<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So what seems to be the problem? Also shouldn't both `http` and `https` redirects fail or succeed together?

Comment: What happens instead of the redirect? Do you have any log lines from whe it hasn't worked as it should?

Comment: Really, Mr Finch, I would have expected that configuring apache would be trivial to you... maybe give Root a call?

Comment: @JennyD Nice try Miss Shaw, I am not letting you anywhere near the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with DNS 'A' and 'AAAA' records for the domain. There is a pre-configured A/AAAA record for `www` which is causing all the issues. I removed them and added a new one `*.example.org`. DNS redirects all wildcard subdomains to the server. The onus is now on the web server on how to deal with them.

It works fine now.

Also check this: [How to redirect all wildcard subdomain to a particular subdomain? Having issues with a subdomain which runs nextcloud server](https://serverfault.com/questions/871339/how-to-redirect-all-wildcard-subdomain-to-a-particular-subdomain-having-issues)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to setup a rewrite, you might want something like this:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
        RewriteEngine On
        # this redirect only www.example.org to https
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org [NC]
        # this redirects anything to its https equivalent
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
   </VirtualHost>`

alternatively, I guess you should simply modify your redirect rule in the `*:80` from `RedirectPermanent / http://example.org`to `RedirectPermanent / https://example.org` . The redirect has to point to https, not http...