# How to redirect all wildcard subdomain to a particular subdomain? Having issues with a subdomain which runs nextcloud server

Tags: apache-2.4, wildcard-subdomain, nextcloud

I want wildcard subdomains that do not exist like `x.example.com`, `y.example.com` etc., to redirect to `404.example.com`.

I am using Apache 2.4. How can I do this?

What I tried:

My 404.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 404.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/web/404"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/404-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/404-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName 404.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/web/404"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/var/web/404">
    Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This actually worked. `123l4k.example.com` gets redirected to `404.example.com`. But the nextcloud subdomain, `nc.example.com`, also redirects to `404.example.com`. **Other subdomains are working fine.**

I have to disable the virutalhost `404.conf` to be able to access the nextcloud subdomain.

My nc.conf:

```
Alias /nextcloud /var/web/nextcloud/

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName nc.example.com
  ServerAlias nextcloud.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/web/nextcloud/"

  RedirectPermanent / https://nc.example.com

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_access.log combined

#RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/nextcloud_rewrite.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName nc.example.com
  ServerAlias nextcloud.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/web/nextcloud/"

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_access.log combined

  SSLCertificateFile /fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>


<Directory "/var/web/nextcloud/">
  Options +FollowSymlinks +ExecCGI
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted

 <IfModule mod_dav.c>
  Dav off
 </IfModule>

 SetEnv HOME "/var/web/nextcloud"
 SetEnv HTTP_HOME "/var/web/nextcloud"
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/web/nextcloud/data/">
  Require local
</Directory>
```

How can I keep the behaviour of wildcard domains redirecting to `404.example.com` and be able to access my nextcloud server on `nc.example.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache webserver reads the vhost config files in alphabetically order. This implies that the `404.conf` files is read before the `nc.conf` file. Thus the host is first matched with the `ServerAlias *.example.com` directive, this matches and the other vhosts are ignored. By renaming the `nc.conf` file to `00_nc.conf` the Nextcloud configuration will be loaded first and thus matched against nextcloud.example.com, and other domain is matched against `404.conf` which is loaded later.

Comment: This is it: The Apache webserver reads the vhost config files in alphabetical order.